# RegEx pattern any two letters followed by six numbers

Tags: regex

Please assist with the proper RegEx matching any 2 letters followed by any combination of 6 whole numbers.

```
These would be valid: 
RJ123456
PY654321
DD321234

These would not
DDD12345
12DDD123
```

Comment: What about "ABC1234567"; might it ever occur?

Comment: There wouldn't be a case for more than two letters or 6 numbers.

Comment: Will the "whole numbers" always be the Western Arabic numerals `0-9`, or will there ever be [other digits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_digit#Numerals_in_most_popular_systems)?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

`[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{6}`

`[a-zA-Z]{2}` means two letters
`\d{6}` means 6 digits

If you want only uppercase letters, then:

`[A-Z]{2}\d{6}`

Comment: you forgot to start with ^, otherwise, if you have more than 2 letters, it will partially match.

Comment: What expression I must use when need text like Alphabet+Number only like `RHX9707` but not `0CA100` and not `KH4X104` and not `HXGGRR`

Only letter then number required

Answer (score 34):

You could try something like this:

```
[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}
```

Here is a break down of the expression:

```
[a-zA-Z]    # Match a single character present in the list below
               # A character in the range between “a” and “z”
               # A character in the range between “A” and “Z”
   {2}         # Exactly 2 times
[0-9]       # Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9”
   {6}         # Exactly 6 times
```

This will match anywhere in a subject. If you need boundaries around the subject then you could do either of the following:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}$
```

Which ensures that the whole subject matches. I.e there is nothing before or after the subject.

or

```
\b[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}\b
```

which ensures there is a [word boundary](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=word%20boundary%20regex&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html&ei=Pv2iT5zIGYmjiQfyq-WpDw&usg=AFQjCNFCKck5wXDyhxXApfhUsfuqmd32rg) on each side of the subject.

As pointed out by @Phrogz, you could make the expression more terse by replacing the `[0-9]` for a `\d` as in some of the other answers.

```
[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{6}
```

Comment: @Phrogz haha, its a matter of preference i guess, i usually use `\d`, but i dunno i felt a little different today. I'll put some more effort in and update it for you.

Comment: @Fergus no worries, i haven't answered anything in a few days, and i was feeling fired up...lol

Comment: Really great catch on ^ and $ without those 2 the regex is NOT going to do what OP expects or wants.

Comment: The boundaries.. Oh my! Have been running around in circles trying to understand why my string wouldn't match consistently! Thank you!!

Comment: What expression I must use when need text like Alphabet+Number only like `RHX9707` but not `0CA100` and not `KH4X104` and not `HXGGRR`

Only letter then number required

Answer (score 8):

I depends on what is the regexp language you use, but informally, it would be:

```
[:alpha:][:alpha:][:digit:][:digit:][:digit:][:digit:][:digit:][:digit:]
```

where `[:alpha:] = [a-zA-Z]`
and `[:digit:] = [0-9]`

If you use a regexp language that allows finite repetitions, that would look like:

```
[:alpha:]{2}[:digit:]{6}
```

The correct syntax depends on the particular language you're using, but that is the idea.

Comment: [[:alpha:]] instead of [:alpha:] to find 2alpha and 6 digits   [[:alpha:]]{2}[[:digit:]]{6}

Answer (score 4):

Everything you need here can be found in [this quickstart guide](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html).
A straightforward solution would be `[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]\d\d\d\d\d\d` or `[A-Za-z]{2}\d{6}`.

If you want to accept only capital letters then replace `[A-Za-z]` with `[A-Z]`.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on if your regex flavor supports it, I might use:

```
\b[A-Z]{2}\d{6}\b    # Ensure there are "word boundaries" on either side, or

(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]{2}\d{6}(?!\d) # Ensure there isn't a uppercase letter before
                              # and that there is not a digit after
```