# One or Two Letters followed by 3-4 numbers

Tags: regex

I am trying to find the correct RegEx pattern to allow one or two letters followed by 3 to 5 numbers and optional One letter at the end.  Finally non-alphanumeric should be allowed to wrap the string:

```
Allowed
M394
,MP4245)
TD493!
X4958A
V49534@
U394U
A5909.

Not Allowed
TED492
R32
R4!3
U394UU
A5909AA
5349A
```

I found an example but it does not quite work:

[RegEx pattern any two letters followed by six numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439666/regex-pattern-any-two-letters-followed-by-six-numbers)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
\b[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\d{3,5}[a-zA-Z]?\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fF5qI5/6)

**Breakup of regex**

```
\b             # word boundary
[a-zA-Z]{1,2}  # 1 or 2 letters
\d{3,5}        # 3 to 5 digits
[a-zA-Z]?      # an optional letter
\b             # word boundary
```

Comment: I don't think `\b` and `\d` are part of the base regex spec.

Comment: This will miss second word `,MP4245)` It does not start with `a-zA-Z`. Neither this is capturing ending with special characters

Comment: OP had `,MP4245)` in allowed list and this regex does allow that line (see demo).

Comment: ok. i think `\b` is doing the trick. i learned new thing today. :)

Answer (score 0):

go on, give it a try. Look at http://regex101.com and it's actually quite easy.

```
^[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]{1,2}[0-9]{3,5}.?[^A-Za-z]*
```

I'd normally suggest using an 'i' (for case insenstive) flag if your RE actually is.

E.g.:

https://regex101.com/r/sR7xG8/1

Answer (score 0):

I think this will fit your need

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9]?[a-zA-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{3,5}[a-zA-Z]?[^a-zA-Z0-9]?
```