# Java REGEX for only numbers

Tags: java, regex

Im working on a personal custom text editor for mysql and this is my issue:

[image]

This is what im currently using, it will highlight any number, i want to exclude  numbers directly concatenated to any letter [A-Za-z], any other symbol is not important since some of them are aritmetic symbols.

`private static final String NUMBER_PATTERN = "[0-9]+";`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx pattern any two letters followed by six numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439666/regex-pattern-any-two-letters-followed-by-six-numbers)

Comment: How about `\b\d+\b`? Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Fzm2PS/1/

Comment: @degant That seems like an answer to me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this regex to select only numbers that aren't connected to any text

```
\b\d+\b
```

- `\d+` allows any number of digits
- `\b` at the start and the end defines a word boundary so that it doesn't match words like `text12`, `9gag`, `4chan` etc

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Fzm2PS/2

```
// Will match 12, 34, 
// Will not match text12, string, 9gag
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a "positive look-behind" construct in your REGEX.

```
"[0-9]+(?<=[a-zA-Z])"
```

Matches:

```
the 9 in "a9"; 
the 10 in "B10"; 
the 9 in "a9A"
```

Doesn't Match:

```
the 9 in "9A"; 
the 10 in "+10"
the 10 in " 10"
```

Answer (score -1):

Java Regular Expression for only numbers is

String regex=".*[a-z].*" // (after the each dot there is *) and then use variable.matches(regex), it will return true if it contains a-z and false if it contains only numbers

Comment: This is not true.  Your regular expression matches "any character" followed by "a lower-case Latin letter between a and z includive" followed by "any character".  It does not match "only numbers" as you say.  What do you even mean that "after each dot there is *"?  I see no *.  Dots match single characters.  dot star matches 0 or more characters.  Perhaps the biggest issue here is that you aren't really answering the specific question that was asked (that wasn't asked very well either).  I feel bad voting down your first answer, but at least you know why.