# how to make avoid user entering numbers for first two chars(but rest all chars must be numbers only) using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have one requirement in form.My form has textbox field "DEA License number".textbox must allow user to enter alphabet only for first two characters and numbers only after two characters.I want to achieve this functionality using javascript.Note:-I dont want validation but avoid user inputting

Comment: This does not conform to the rubrick of a good question. Please add some code and review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using regex?

Take a look at this post which has a very similar goal: [RegEx pattern any two letters followed by six numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439666/regex-pattern-any-two-letters-followed-by-six-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

Try use some of masked textbox.

For example:

https://css-tricks.com/input-masking/

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

You can easily test this with a regex:

```
function isValid(str) {
    return /^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d+$/.test(str);
}
```

I am not quite sure what you mean by "I dont want validation but avoid user inputting." If you mean that you don't want the user to be able to type an invalid character, this could theoretically be done with an `input` event handler:

```
var oldValue = "";
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  var value = e.target.value;
  if ((value.length <= 2 && /^[a-zA-Z]*$/.test(value)) || value.length > 2 && /^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d+$/.test(value)) oldValue = value
  else e.target.value = oldValue;
})
```

However, you'd still need to validate it when it's submitted since the user could've entered an incomplete value.