# Regexp regular expression for selecting particular string pattern from SELECT query

Tags: mysql, regex

String will be consider valid if it starts with letters MS and must contain numeric values 0-9, maximum numeric values allowed are 7.

**Valid strings :**

```
MS1234567

MS3434344

MS4534523
```

**Invalid sting:**

```
  MS1234567-V2

    MS3434344:old

    YU4534523

    MS4534523768

TY4534523DEL
```

This the query I tried, I am getting blank result. Where I am going wrong

```
SELECT MY_STRING_COLUMN
FROM MY_TABLE_NAME
WHERE  `MY_STRING_COLUMN` REGEXP '^[MS]{2}\d{7}';
```

Reference I got from this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439666/regex-pattern-any-two-letters-followed-by-six-numbers)

Comment: Remove the brackets and the quantifier `{2}`, add anchor - `^MS\d{7}$` (MySQL 8+) / `^MS[0-9]{7}$` (MySQL before 8). `[MS]` only matches a single char, `M` or `S`, thus `[MS]{2}` matches `MM`, `SS`, `SM`, or `MS`. Without `$`, you may match the pattern just at the start of the string, but there may be much more than that later.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm not sure that `\d` works with MySQL's `REGEXP`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It will in MySQL 8.x

Comment: How do you know the OP is using MySQL 8+?

Comment: A lot of people are migrating to the newer version.

Comment: Let me check on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `[0-9]` to represent a digit in your regex pattern:

```
SELECT MY_STRING_COLUMN
FROM MY_TABLE_NAME
WHERE MY_STRING_COLUMN REGEXP '^MS[0-9]{7}$';
```

Also note that if you want to match `MS` at the start of the string, just use `^MS`.

Comment: Thanks..let me run this REGEXP!

Comment: (Note: MySQL 8.0 and MariaDB do allow `\d`.)