# Recognizing Alpha-Numeric Strings in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I have some data that looks like this:

```
var1 = c("name1", "name2 A2L 7O1", "1726A")
var2 = c("B6U 5T3", "dog55", "name name K8GG 2H3")
var3 = c("cat J5C 99W3", "A37L2" ,"cat K8Y 9S2 dog")
problem_data = data.frame(var1,var2,var3)

           var1               var2            var3
1         name1            B6U 5T3    cat J5C 99W3
2 name2 A2L 7O1              dog55           A37L2
3         1726A name name K8GG 2H3 cat K8Y 9S2 dog
```

I want the final result to look like this:

```
        var1               var2            var3     var4
1         name1            B6U 5T3    cat J5C 99W3  B6U 5T3
2 name2 A2L 7O1              dog55           A37L2  A2L 7O1
3         1726A name name K8GG 2H3 cat K8Y 9S2 dog K8Y 9S2
```

Basically, In every row, I want to recognize any consecutive pattern of  LETTER NUMBER LETTER NUMBER LETTER NUMBER .

I have been trying to find different ways to do this in R. I have been trying to use this link for inspiration ([RegEx pattern any two letters followed by six numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439666/regex-pattern-any-two-letters-followed-by-six-numbers)). I tried to understand the logic behind REGEX, but I  am feeling very lost and tried a very indirect way in which I generate different permutations of LETTER NUMBER LETTER NUMBER LETTER NUMBER:

```
    letter_1 = LETTERS
    number_1 = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
    letter_2 = LETTERS
    number_2 = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
    letter_3 = LETTERS
    number_3 = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
    
all <- expand.grid(letter_1, number_1, letter_2, number_2, letter_3, number_3, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
 perms <- all[apply(all, 1, function(x) {length(unique(x)) == 3}),]
```

But I think there are too many permutations to generate.

Any faster way to do this?

Comment: Not sure if I'm misreading your question, but you say that you want LNLNLN with no spaces, but the example input -> output you provide HAS spaces, eg. B6U 5T3

Comment: @ 
Aggragoth : thanks for your comment! I took that out - in general, I am just trying to find LNLNLN (space or no space).

Comment: Have you tried `([A-Z]\d){3}` ? Which in laymans terms is just "LN" 3 times

Comment: [A-Za-z] will match any alphabetical character, upper or lowercase and \d will match any digit, its equivalent to [0-9]. The {3} is just how many times you want that to appear

Comment: Sorry. To correct my previous comments, you wanted spaces in there too, so you can do something like `([A-Za-z]\b\d\b){3}`
The `\b` character is a word boundary, which could be a space, the start/end of the string, etc

Comment: @Aggragoth : Thank you so much! How would I apply this code in my question?

Comment: unfortunately I'm not sure. I'm not very familiar with R, but maybe you're able to check each column of your dataframe for matches of that regex and then just copy its value into the extra column? You'd probably have more knowledge of how to perform that sort of operation than I do

Comment: `apply(problem_data, 1, function(x) gsub('(([A-Z] ?[0-9]){3})|.', '\\1', toString(x)))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```r
library(stringr)
regex <- '\\b\\p{L}\\s?\\d(?:\\s?\\p{L}\\s?\\d){2}\\b'
problem_data$var4 <- apply(problem_data, 1, function(x) str_extract(toString(x), regex))
```

Output:

```r
> problem_data
           var1               var2            var3    var4
1         name1            B6U 5T3    cat J5C 99W3 B6U 5T3
2 name2 A2L 7O1              dog55           A37L2 A2L 7O1
3         1726A name name K8GG 2H3 cat K8Y 9S2 dog K8Y 9S2
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oAIXVt/1). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `\p{L}` - a letter
- `\s?` - an optional whitespace
- `\d` - a digit
- `(?:\s?\p{L}\s?\d){2}` - two sequences of an optional whitespace, a letter, an optional whitespace, a digit
- `\b` - a word boundary